# Product Categories not showing up on Appearance > Menus and on UX Builder of Flatsome Theme

Tags: wordpress

I am working on `WordPress 5.2` and with a `Flatsome Theme 3.8.3`

When I create new Product Categories via Products **=>** Categories

I can't find them when I design the Menus via  Appearance **=>** Menus

On the left sections of the Menus editing page on WP here are the sections I have :
 
Pages
Posts
 
Custom Links
Categories
WooCommerce endpoints

There is NO SIGH OF PRODUCT CATEGORIES

Can you please help me figure this out ? 
I need to have the PRODUCT CATEGORIES section on Menu editing page so I can add the category tab to the right and add it to my main menu.

Answer (score 1):

Open Screen options at the top of your page and check the appropriate box(es).

Comment: You're very welcome. I had the same issue a few days ago.